# Insert Into a table a variable outside of the SELECT results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working on a Stored Procedure on MSSQL. This is a simplified example of my case.

```
another code that has declared a variable @Country
...
...
...
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers;
```

So, what I try to do is instead of the `Country` value of the `SELECT`, insert the `@Country` variable of the previous code, but keep the `SupplierName` from the results.

I wasn't able to find a similar question and trial and error didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the variable instead:

```
Insert Into Customers (CustomerName, Country)
Select SupplierName, @Country 
From Suppliers;
```

Comment: When your tests are far more complicated than the simplest solution! Thank you. Will check it as the best in 4 minutes due to time limit.

Answer (score 1):

Well someone beat me to the punch (@Siyual), but just use the variable in the select (example of this below)

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1 (
    id INT,
    value INT
    )

CREATE TABLE #temp2 (
    id INT,
    value INT
    )

DECLARE @newVal INT

SET @newVal = 10

INSERT INTO #temp1 (
    id,
    value
    )
VALUES (
    1,
    1
    )

INSERT INTO #temp1 (
    id,
    value
    )
VALUES (
    2,
    2
    )

INSERT INTO #temp1 (
    id,
    value
    )
VALUES (
    3,
    3
    )

INSERT INTO #temp2 (
    id,
    value
    )
SELECT id,
    @newVal
FROM #temp1

SELECT *
FROM #temp2
```